# Применение enum на реальных проектах

Tags: c#, enum

Применяют ли на реальных проектах перечисления `enum`? Если да, то в каких use-case? Я читал, что с данными типами в будущем могут появиться проблемы, связанные с управлением версиями ([тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/enum) источник)

У меня есть класс `ChessFigure`, у которого есть свойство `Colour`. Хочу сделать перечисление "Black" и "White", но не уверен, что это нужно (альтернатива: свойство сделать типа `bool` и переименовать его в `IsWhite`).

**UPD.** Цель, которую я преследую - создать удобно поддерживаемую библиотеку классов.

Comment: Жестко вписывайте значения (White = 1) для enum-ов и не меняйте их на другие в будущих версиях, только добавляйте новые - и проблем не будет.

Comment: @PashaPash Спасибо за объяснение!) Скажите, а часто ли применяют перечисления на проектах? (P.S. сам пока не работаю). Мне хотелось бы узнать, какой вариант реализации свойства `Colour` предпочтительнее в данном случае.

Comment: @AndreiKhotko, в дотнете куча перечислений

Comment: эх, как мне не хватает в C# delphi-евских энумераторов, на которых можно определять массивы

Comment: @Igor, ну в принципе ты можешь свою обертку с индексатором сделать и все :-)

Comment: @Grundy да, часто так и делаю. Но там есть еще такая ценная вещь, как проверка компилятором размера константного массива, заданного на базе enum-а.

Comment: @Igor, эм? про что это?

Comment: @Grundy внизу написал

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Да, конечно используется. Например, в проекте, над которым я сейчас работаю, ровно 125 `enum`'ов.

Из двух вариантов `bool IsBlack` или `enum PieceColor { White, Black }` второй вариант кажется мне более предпочтительным.

Например, вы не сможете при втором варианте случайно присвоить несвязанное булево значение: `IsBlack = IsGameSaved` скомпилируется, а `Color = IsGameSaved` — нет.

Кроме того, если у вас функция выглядит как

```
void MakeMove(bool isBlack) { ... }
```

то глядя на код `MakeMove(true)`, нужно ещё вспомнить, что же означает это самое `true`: белый цвет, чёрный, или вообще живого игрока в отличие от противостоящего ему искусственного интеллекта. С вызовом `MakeMove(PieceColor.White)` вопросов не возникает.

Так что да, для удобства лучше использовать `enum`'ы.

Comment: Не вижу ничего плохого в `IsBlack = IsGameSaved`. Фигурка на кнопке сохранения становится чёрной, если игра сохранена, всё логично.

Comment: @Squidward: Ну, это из серии «присвоим возрасту в миллисекундах расстояние до Альфа Центавра в парсеках». То есть это случайно _может_ быть правильным, но этот код выглядит подозрительно, и нуждается в поясняющем комментарии (что само по себе уже плохо). Ну и у ТС чёрные и белые фигуры на доске, а не иконка состояния сохранения (для этой иконки свойство `IsBlack` малоосмысленно, т. к. не скинируется). В общем, эта сова на глобус не натягивается.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!) Скажите пожалуйста, а `enum` лучше оформлять как отдельный файл `enumName.cs` или в файле класса, в котором он используется?

Comment: @AndreiKhotko: Ну, вроде бы правильнее в отдельном файле, хотя я чаще всего не заморачиваюсь, и кладу в файл класса, где этот enum используется.

Answer (score 4):

Например у Вас есть сущность товара в магазине. У него допустим есть ряд состояний :

```
В наличии.
Снят с продажи.
Возможна доставка.
```

В базе Вы определенно будете это хранить в виде `tinyint` ( 0,1,2). А на коде, отражать через enum, что очень сильно облегчает читаемость кода, вам не надо будет помнить что такое 1, а что такое 2.

Comment: Полезная информация, спасибо! :) До этого подобного рода задачи решал через строки и сравнение строк.

Answer (score 0):

Если ты роботаеш с Api и у тебя есть набор допустимых значений, удобно использовать enum.
e.g.

> Returns candlestick chart data. Required GET parameters are
>   "currencyPair", "period" (candlestick period in seconds; valid values
>   are 300, 900, 1800, 7200, 14400, and 86400).

```
internal enum Period
    {
        S300 = 300,
        S900 = 900, 
        ...
    }
```

Удобние делать enum, что бы не делать лишних проверок

```
returnChartData(some arg, ..., Period perior){
}
```